# CAS server Tomcat 8 Java 8 High Availability (HA/Clustering)

Tags: java, tomcat, redis, cas, high-availability

I'm going to implement High Availability (HA/Clustering) for my Jasig CAS server at AWS infrastructure on Java 8 and Tomcat 8.

I'll use multiple CAS server nodes architecture.

Also, I plan to use `Tomcat SessionManager` that persists data(sessions) into Redis. The same things with `CAS Ticket Registry`  - I plan to store cas tickets into Redis.

Right now I can't find any official implementation of Tomcat Redis SessionManager and CAS server Redis Ticket Registry.

I have found only some custom stuff -

[Cas Ticket Redis](https://github.com/izerui/cas-ticket-redis)

[Tomcat SessionManager that persists data into Redis](https://github.com/pivotalsoftware/session-managers)

Is it a good idea to use Redis for this purpose ? If so, could you please recommend some proven implementations for CAS server Redis Ticket Registry and Tomcat 8 Redis SessionManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAS does not officially support Redis in form of a ticket registry. There are other options available such as Hazelcast, Ehcache, etc. Session replication is not required.

Comment: Thanks, instead of Session replication I'll use AWS ELB Sticky sessions. It should fix the issue.

Comment: I mean  - in additional to Redis Ticket Registry I'll also use AWS ELB Sticky sessions

Comment: If you do have a redis ticket registry available, feel free to publish a pull request.

Comment: I have reused a following code https://github.com/izerui/cas-ticket-redis  So far everything works properly( HA CAS server(AWS ELB( Sticky sessions enabled) + 2 EC2 instances with Tomcat8)) + AWS ElasticCache with Redis engine HA (2 Nodes) I'm not the author of this `RedisTicketRegistry` so I'm not sure this is a good idea to publish a pull request. I think some one from Jasig CAS team can ask the author directly for pull request.

Comment: Also, one remark - in order to proper use serialization(for example to Redis) with CAS you have to use CAS server >= 4.1.3 verison

Comment: Very cool. I don't see a license or author tag associated with any of the source files, so I don't think there would be a problem with CAS picking this up.

Comment: Also note that CAS supports Infinispan Cache, which claims to support Redis as the backend cache.